# How to install data management gate way in HDInsight Cluster?

Tags: azure, hdfs, gateway, azure-hdinsight

I created Windows platform HDInsight Cluster in azure. And then logged into Cluster by using remote desktop credentials after that I am trying to install data management gateway.

I followed the below link to install data management gateway for connecting HDFS: [Move data between on-premises sources and the cloud with Data Management Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud#create-gateway)

Whenever I run the msi file in HD Insight Cluster I got the error like “**the system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation**”. For that I followed this link: [The System Administrator has set policies to prevent this installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/580972/why-is-this-preventing-me-installing-an-msi-the-system-administrator-has-set-po) but I am able to set the reg key under installer even I run the regedit in “Run as Administrator”.

So, how can I install data management gate way in HDInsight Cluster?